# Правильно ли оформлено предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в предложении!

Другими словами, предприятия, связанные цепочкой: проектирование, производство, эксплуатация, обслуживание, должны, и на практике используют, разные составляющие интегрированного решения по поддержке ЖЦИ.

Мне кажется, должна быть следующая редакция:

Другими словами, предприятия, связанные цепочкой «проектирование — производство — эксплуатация — обслуживание», должны и на практике используют разные составляющие интегрированного решения по поддержке ЖЦИ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*>> должны и на практике используют разные составляющие*

...должны использовать и используют на практике...

Comment: А то, что тафтология получается?.. Или это здесь допускается?

Comment: Ну и что... Тавтология далеко не всегда недостаток. Должны (что?) – слово-то пропущено. Оно угадывается из контекста, но все же я бы его не пропускал.